# PHP/MySQL -- What does || mean?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set up a simple php/mysql database on my website and the example has a line that says:

```
 if (!$searchtype || !?searchterm) {
```

What are the ||??? I tried to copy and paste them but they cause syntax errors. Noob question I know, but would love an answer nonetheless!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its `||(OR)` [logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

> $a || $b   Or  TRUE if either/both $a or $b is TRUE.

and it should be

```
if (!$searchtype || !searchterm) {
```

as in op [this Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697285/php-mysql-what-does-mean/13697296#comment18808319_13697296) you can write this by

[image]

Comment: Either `$a` or `$b` or both. Because there's also `xor`, which is either `$a` or `$b` but not both.

Answer (score 2):

I think the code actually is :

```
 if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
```

`||` means OR operator, meaning conditions is satisfied if either of the condition is true.

Comment: See what lies just below the backspace key.

Comment: I found them on the keyboard above the enter button. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its an `OR` logical operator for handling conditions:

Ex :

```
$a || $b
```

Or  TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.

See : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

for more details